# Correctly passing and manipulating hierarchical data between parent and child components in React

Tags: reactjs, nested, components

I am very new to React and, in my current project, am looking to display hierarchical data I get from a DB and have the user be able to change different parts of it using various child components.

As a stupid example, consider the following JSON:

```
export const myData = [
    {
        Id: 1,
        Name: "John Bustos",
        Location: "USA",
        Assets: [
            {
                Category: {
                    Type: "Food"
                    Items: [
                        {
                            Item: 
                                {
                                    Name: "Hamburger",
                                    Status: "In Fridge"
                                },
                            Item: 
                                {
                                    Name: "Grapes",
                                    Status: "In Fridge"
                                },
                        }
                    ]
                }
                Category: {
                    Type: "Clothing"
                    Items: [
                        {
                            Item: 
                                {
                                    Name: "Sweater",
                                    Status: "In Laundry"
                                },
                            Item: 
                                {
                                    Name: "Jeans",
                                    Status: "In Hamper"
                                },
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

So, in my project, I would have:

1. A parent component that shows the top-level data (`Name`, `Location`)
2. Child components holding each of the 2 asset categories (`Food` & `Clothing`)
3. Sub-child components holding each item within each category (`Hamburger` & `Grapes` showing up within `Food`; `Sweater` & `Jeans` within `Clothing`)

I have been able to show the data using the child components and passing the JSON down from the parent, but my issue comes about in trying to make it such that the user can add in new `Categories` or remove what's currently there as well as having the same add-in / remove ability for the the `Items` within each category.

From what I understand of React, I believe that I need to have the parent component (that actually gets this JSON object) have the functions to manipulate the JSON (eg: `addCategory`, `removeCategory`, `addItem`, `removeItem`) and passing them, along with the relevant pieces of the JSON to the child, which will then pass it through to the sub-child.

This seems like I am WAAY over-coupling my components, and gets even worse if I have a third level of children I need to do this for, but I don't know / can't think how else this should be done correctly.

Is this the right way to do this and, if not (which I'm guessing it isn't), what would the correct way be?

Comment: Sounds like you've a great candidate case for using the React [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) so you don't need to explicitly pass down the state and updaters to each level of components. I'd even go as far as to say you should just make the jump to using Redux as state management. See [redux-toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/), which allows you to define ***how** each chunk (or slice) of state should be updated, and components can select out the chunks of state they want to render.

Comment: Oooooh. Very cool, @DrewReese. All new to me - Going to check it out now. Thank you!

Comment: @DrewReese, I did end up using your suggestion and it was exactly what I needed - If you'd like to post it as an answer, I'll happily accept it. Thank you again!

Comment: No worries, and that's great to hear. If you'd posted more in your question to work from I might've answered instead. Cheers and good luck.